# required vs [Required] in C# 11

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

C# 11 has introduced, required modifier, which can be used a below:

```
    public required string FirstName { get; init; }
    public required string LastName { get; init; }
```

```
[Required]
public required string FirstName { get; init; }
```

Just wanted to understand the difference between [Required] attribute and required modifier.
Read the documentation but did not understand.

Tried reading documentation

Comment: `[Required]` attribute is a data validation attribute which can be triggered during runtime, `required` modifier is used to denote required property during initialization, it is explained quite well in the article - https://newdevsguide.com/2022/11/12/csharp-11-required-keyword/

Comment: I would like to know whether ASP.NET Core can look at required keyword on models and consider that for runtime validation.

Answer (score 11):

The required keyword indicates that the field must be set during initialization. For example

```
public class User
{   
    public required string Username { get; set; }
    public required string Password{ get; set; }
}
```

If you try to set a new user
User newuser=new User(); would create an error since you have two required fields but you haven't set them in initialization of the variable.

For the [Required] attribute

```
public class User
{   
    
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password{ get; set; }
}
```

I would be able to create a new instance of User
User newUser= new User();

But when a new user on a form is validated, the field must contain a value for Password.

Comment: Agreed. [Required] is for data validation and in many cases work with ef, and required keyword is c# general.

Answer (score 0):

Can we said that the use of required modifier is a way to simplify the constructor?

version without "required" modifier:

```
class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string DomainName { get; set; }

    public Employee(string firstName, string lastName, string domainName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        DomainName = domainName;
        CreateUserName();
        CreateEmailAddress();
    }
}
```

version with "required" modifier:

```
class Employee
{
    public required string FirstName { get; set; }
    public required string LastName { get; set; }
    public required string DomainName { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
        CreateUserName();
        CreateEmailAddress();
    }
}
```